# WebSocket create issue

Tags: android, networking, websocket, em-websocket

Am creating a WebSocket application which will connect with wss url (say wss://someurl).
I got some sample code from here https://github.com/elabs/mobile-websocket-example which is simple chat app. This is working fine for **ws** protocol. But when I replace it with my **wss** url, it throwing error as **"refuses handshake"**

I tried autobahn as well, but it seems wss protocol is not supported. Even I tried to different samples just to connect with my socket server, but no help.

P.S : I was able to do socket connection properly in iOS platform. I am facing this issue only in android.

Comment: are your SSL certificate(s) ok?

Comment: @Tasos - You mean @ server side ? I think yes, because I was able to connect it from iOS app

Comment: yes. are they self signed? you need to check cause they may have expired